# Bash: Filter directory when piping from `ls` to `tee`

Tags: bash, sed, grep

(background info)

Writing my first bash psuedo-program. The program downloads a bunch of files from the network, stores them in a sub-directory called `./network-files/`, then removes all the files it downloaded. It also logs the result to several log files in `./logs/`.

I want to log the filenames of each file deleted.

---

Currently, I'm doing this:

`echo -e "$(date -u) >>> Removing files: $(ls -1 "$base_directory"/network-files/* | tr '\n' ' ')" | tee -a $network_files_log $verbose_log $network_log`

(`$base_directory` is a variable defining the base directory for the app, `$network_files_log` etc are variables defining the location of various log files)

This produces some pretty grody and unreadable output:

`Tue Jun 21 04:55:46 UTC 2016 >>> Removing files: /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/207822218.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/217311040.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/442119100.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/464324101.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/525787337.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/581100197.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/640387393.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/650797708.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/827538696.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/833069509.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/8580204.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/858174053.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/998266826.png`

**Any good way to strip out the `/home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/` part from each of those file paths?** I suspect there's something I should be doing with `sed` or `grep`, but haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it a couple of ways.  To directly answer the question, you could use `sed` to do it with the substitution command like:

```
echo -e "$(date -u) >>> Removing files: $(ls -1 "$base_directory"/network-files/* | tr '\n' ' ')" | sed -e "s,$base_directory/network-files/,," | tee -a $network_files_log $verbose_log $network_log
```

which adds `sed -e "s,$base_directory/network-files/,,"` to the pipeline.  It will substitute the string found in `base_directory` with the empty string, so long as there are not any commas in `base_directory`.  If there are you could try a different separator for the parts of the sed command, like underscore: `sed -e "s_$base_directory/network-files__"`

Instead though, you could just have the subshell `cd` to that directory and then the string wouldn't be there in the first place:

```
echo -e "$(date -u) >>> Removing files: $(cd "$base_directory/network-files/"; ls -1 | tr '\n' ' ')" | tee -a "$network_files_log" "$verbose_log" "$network_log"
```

Or you could avoid some potential pitfalls with [`echo` and use `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) like

```
{ printf '%s >>>Removing files: '; printf '%s ' "$(cd "$base_directory/network-files"; ls -1)"; printf '\n'; } | tee -a ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't really understood that the `$(cd)` construct creates an independent subshell, and had worried about somehow messing up the working directory for the parent shell. I'll read more on `printf` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider using [find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html). Its perfect for walking directories, removing files and using customized *printf* for output:

```
   find $PWD/x -type f -printf "%f\n" -delete >>$YourLogFile.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ls` at all; use a glob to populate an array with the desired files. You can then use parameter expansion to shorten each array element.

```
d=$base_directory/network-files
files=( "$d"/* )
printf '%s Removing files: %s' "$(date -u)" "${files[*]#$d/}" | tee ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testdata="/home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/207822218.png /home/vagrant/load-simulator/network-files/217311040.png"
echo -e $testdata | sed -e 's/\/[^ ]*\///g'
```

Pipe your output to sed the replace that captured group with nothing.

The regex: `\/[^ ]*\/`

Start with a `/`, captured everything that is not a space until it gets to the last `/`.